# Minimum window in string 1 which contains string 2 as a subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Two large strings say 2 DNA sequences - S1, S2 are given. Find out the minimum length window in S1 which contains S2 as a subsequence i.e; S2 may be a substring of the window in S1 or s2 may be a subsequence in the window in S1 also.

Any dynamic programming based algorithm for this purpose?

Comment: What complexity are you seeking? Have you tried the trivial O(n^2) algorithm?

Comment: Trivial approach is not what I need. I am seeking for anything better.

Comment: How exactly is this problem different than the *Longest Common Subsequence* problem?

Comment: It could be a variation of LCS. But how to modify the LCS algorithm to find the desired answer?